# What are these mushrooms found in Fukuoka, Japan?

Tags: food, fungi-identification, mushrooms, fungi

The mushrooms were picked in a public park in Fukuoka, Japan. Can someone help to identify them please?[image: Mushrooms-Fukuoka-Japan]

Comment: A picture with the whole mushroom would be helpful in [identifying them](http://urbanmushrooms.com/index.php?id=69).

Comment: I believe the picture has not only the whole mushrooms but the vertical and horizontal dissections.

Comment: Hi Nutkin! I thought I could Google this and have an ID in no time but it's harder than it looks! I think they're in the shiitake or matsutake family. Matsutakes are extremely rare but Japan is one of their few native places in the world. The Fukuoka region is well known for its mushrooms. There's even an annual  [Fukuoka Mushroom Festival](http://www.fukuoka-now.com/en/event/fukuoka-mushroom-festival-2016/)!

Comment: I have a few questions. Were these in the ground or attached to a tree? What kind of trees are in that park? Were they individual, or did you have to break any apart from a clump? Are you sure they're all the same? Some look different, which could mean there's more than one kind, or it could be one kind at different life stages. Do you still have them? If you do, would you smell them and describe the odor?  Are they squishy to the touch or firm? Would you edit that information into the question rather than a comment? Thanks! Hopefully we'll figure this out!

Comment: Are you looking to ID for edibility? A spore print would also be helpful. Also, it looks like this is an industrialized/highly urbanized area. Before eating even confirmed edible mushrooms from such an area, I'd want to know if any pesticides are used in the park's management. Also there is a minimum distance from roads that is considered safe for foraging (50 - 150' depending on traffic and who you talk to).

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from photo, but: "gills" look yellow which is wrong for a button /agaricus compestri . Do they have gills ? If they have a spongy matter and not gills they are likely some boletin . Usually found under conifers. If so, likely edible but not much flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Masshurumu Button Point to button on your shirt. Fairly expensive in Japan. That type fresh. Grown commercial there. Or wild. Close as I can come.

Comment: Been to Japan. Have bought them at the store.& the white ones. Masshurumu is how you say mushroom in Japan. I stick to picking wild mushrooms in the Philippines.

Comment: Lookup edable mushrooms Japan. There you will find photos of 5 type. I think you will find those there to study.